# How does a gravitational field behave when it heats up?

Tags: thermodynamics, gravity, spacetime

If gravity involves curvature in space-time and heat involves vibrations (e.g. of atoms), then presumably heating the gravitational field should cause vibrations in space-time, but it is unclear to me what the consequences of vibrating space-time would look like.

Comment: I think what is being asked here is whether or not a hot object will, through the random motions of its atoms, set up similarly random gravitational waves in the space-time fabric, and if so, what that would look like or do. Is this right?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly is meant by "heating the gravitational field".

Comment: This is a very cool question. I hope someone answers it for you.